Is there an easier way to smoothly attach one mesh to another?
I've been modeling a plane, which has a ton of smoothly connected parts and i am not sure how to connect these "fins":


These are 2 separate objects that I would like to smoothly flow into the plane's body. I thought about using a shrinkwrap modifier, but I'm afraid it will take ages to make it look decent.
Are there any other ways to achieve this kind of smooth connection? Or any tips for using the shrinkwrap?
Example of connection I'm talking about:


Uses a shrinkwrap and DataTransfer(Custom normals) modifiers

